# List remote branches in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch

Is there a way to list remote branches in Mercurial like there in Git?

```
git branch -r
```

I want to list the branches on a remote machine (e.g. Bitbucket), so using:

```
hg branches -R `hg showconfig paths.default` --color false
```

fails with abort: repository not local

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it is not possible to list branches of a remote repository without cloning it to local.

If there is SSH access to the machine having the remote repository, then Mercurial could be used directly: `ssh server hg -R path/to/repo branches`.

If the repository is served with hgweb, then a list of branches can be fetched from that, using the raw style for easy parsing: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/branches?style=raw

BitBucket has its own API, where it is possible to get the branches, see [their help](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BBDEV/Repositories) and make a query like to a URL like https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/mirror/mercurial/branches/

Comment: Yep that's what I'd come to suspect.  Thanks for the useful info about hgweb and bitbucket though.

Comment: I wonder why mercurial designed this way? I can get revision of particular branch using `hg id -r <branch name> <remote repository>`, but cannot get list of all branches..

Comment: It *does* work if the "remote" repository is on the same host and specified by a file path.  i.e., if `.hg/hgrc` or `hg paths default` just shows a path and not, e.g,. an ssh URI.  This way you can see branches that are still remote in the sense that they have not been pulled.

Answer (score 21):

The mercurial API allows it:

```py
from mercurial import ui, hg, node

peer = hg.peer(ui.ui(), {}, 'http://hg.python.org/cpython')
for name, rev in peer.branchmap().items():
    print(name, node.short(rev[0]))
```

The above snippet produces:

```
default aaa68dce117e
legacy-trunk b77918288f7d
3.2 4787b9b2f860
3.0 4cd9f5e89061
3.1 5a6fa1b8767f
2.3 364638d6434d
2.2 61b0263d6881
2.1 e849d484029f
2.0 5fd74354d73b
2.7 260f3ad7af4b
2.6 f130ce67387d
2.5 b48e1b48e670
2.4 ceec209b26d4
```

Comment: How do you run such a script as that?

Comment: You put the snippet in a file and call it with `python filename.py`. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thanks. I just wasn't sure what language it was.

Comment: Seems to work! I wish this were a standard command (or option, or extension) though.

Comment: Also: add `from sys import argv` and replace hard-coded URL with `argv[1]` to allow the URL to be specified as a command-line argument.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on @gvalkov’s answer, you can make this a real extension by writing a file `rheads.py`:

```py
from mercurial import hg, commands, cmdutil, node
cmdtable = {}
command = cmdutil.command(cmdtable)
@command('rheads', commands.remoteopts, 'hg rheads [SOURCE]')
def rheads(ui, repo, source='default', **opts):
    """print (possibly remote) heads

    Prints a series of lines consisting of hashes and branch names.
    Specify a local or remote repository, defaulting to the configured remote.
    """
    other = hg.peer(ui or repo, opts, ui.expandpath(source))
    for tag, heads in other.branchmap().iteritems():
        for h in heads:
            ui.write("%s %s\n" % (node.short(h), tag))
```

When configured in `~/.hgrc` with

```
[extensions]
rheads = …/rheads.py
```

you can run it like:

```
hg rheads
```

I tried to make it a command that can be invoked outside any repository, just specifying the URL as an argument, but could not get the syntax to work:

```py
commands.norepo += " rheads"
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you are looking for `hg incoming -B` This worked quite well for me. This shows the bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

**Please note, this will not display *remote only* branches, it will only show branches that your local repository is aware of.**

As the only relevant question to appear when googling "hg command line list branches", I thought I'd leave this here. When you run the following -

`hg log | grep "branch" | grep -v "summary" | sort --unique`

it outputs;

```
branch:      branch1
branch:      branch2
branch:      branch3
branch:      branch4
branch:      branch5
```