# get the tip revision informations from mercurial API

Tags: python, api, mercurial

How can I get the tip revision informations of a remote mercurial repository from a python script?

I want something like:`hg tip`.
AFAIK hg commands needs a local repository.

I found another approach with mercurial API : [List remote branches in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296636/list-remote-branches-in-mercurial).
But I can't find a documentation on mercurial API to go further this way.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Nit: That's not the "mercurial API" the Mercurial team is very explicit that the Mercurial API is the command line and everything internal is not the API and is subject to change at any time.  By all means use it, but it can and does break from version to version whereas the command line has 100% backward compatibility.  You're better off using the ssh based command line usage as shown in the selected answer of the question to which you linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the "official" way to do it (based on the selected answer to which you linked):

```
$ ssh ry4an.org hg -R /srv/hg/unblog id -r tip
30117899846f tip
```

If you don't have ssh access to the remote repo then you probably have hgweb access, which makes information about the most tip commit availble at a URL like this: http://ry4an.org/hg/unblog/raw-rev/tip

You can definitely use the Mercurial internals as seen in @resi's excellent answer, but be sure you're aware it's [actively discouraged](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialApi?highlight=%28api%29#Why_you_shouldn.27t_use_Mercurial.27s_internal_API).

Comment: You are, of course, right. I usually do such things as throw-away stuff 'cause I need it just "now" or for a couple of days. Or I'm in a stable (in the sense of rarely updated) environment. My solution is not suitable for wide-spread production use.

Comment: Yeah, it's good to have both approaches spelled out. Each is appropriate in different settings.

Comment: Thank you. I had issues with comments on hgweb which have non ascii characters. I finally found the `encoding = UTF-8` directive in the `[web]` section. So I use hgweb in raw format and parse it. But I think it's far slower compared to have remote commands.

Comment: I'd expect the most time consuming part of any of the 3 methods to be tcp connection establishment, which should be the same for all three, but all of them should be in the 100ms range.

Answer (score 1):

It works similar to the second answer in your link ([List remote branches in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296636/list-remote-branches-in-mercurial)):

```
from mercurial import ui, hg, node

peer = hg.peer(ui.ui(), {}, 'http://hg.python.org/cpython')
print node.short(peer.lookup("tip"))
```

I've tested this with mercurial 2.3.2, for more information you might want to take a look at wireproto.py (class wirepeer).

Comment: Thx resi, but as Ry4an said, it's highly discouraged.
I'm very surprised the hg command toolbox does not allow fetching informations without the need of a local repository.