# Configure Jenkins to build from a user selected Mercurial Branch

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, branch, selector

I'm wondering if anyone has come across how to configure Jenkins to fetch branches from the Mercurial repository so that they can be used in a parameterized job, and instead of manually typing the branch name as a string parameter you can select it from a drop down list?

I found that this is relatively easy with Git, like:

- https://www.devdummy.com/2019/01/configure-jenkins-to-build-from-user.html
- [Select branch to build in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640028/select-branch-to-build-in-jenkins)

to name a few, but is that possible with hg?

Comment: Yes, the same way as defined in *your solution (2)*, just use slightly different command in order to prepare file or inside Groovy-script for getting branch-list (+ change regexp in `it.replaceAll ....`)

Comment: Or just use solutions [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296636/list-remote-branches-in-mercurial)